# Twisted GZIP support

Tags: gzip, twisted

I am trying to serve part of a twisted web site with gzip encoding:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.server import Site, GzipEncoderFactory
from twisted.web.resource import Resource, EncodingResourceWrapper
from twisted.web import server, resource, static


class SharedRoot(resource.Resource):
    """Root resource that combines the two sites/entry points"""

    def getChild(self, child, request):
        request.prepath.pop()
        request.postpath.insert(0, child)
        return self

    def render(self, request):
        return ""

   def render_POST(self, request):
       return ''

class GzipFileResource(static.File):        
    def getChild(self, path, request):
        child = super(GzipFileResource, self).getChild(path, request)            
        return EncodingResourceWrapper(child, [GzipEncoderFactory()])

def main():
    shared=SharedRoot()
    shared.putChild("compressed",GzipFileResource("static"))
    shared.putChild("plain", static.File("static"))
    thisSite=server.Site(shared)
    reactor.listenTCP(8000, thisSite)
    reactor.run()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Server short files works in plain and compressed mode. Serving longer file (>32 KB) only works in plain mode. The browser hangs.

Comment: This needs a lot more information: which browser, which operating system, are you running the browser and the server on the same or different machines, have you tried a command-line tool like `wget` or `curl`, et cetera et cetera.

Comment: Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63 m on Windows 8.1. Server on same machine. Same result with Firefox(29.0a1) on W8.1 or from Firefox(23.0.1) Windows NT. Download does work with curl from OS X (but curl does not set accept-encoding), so content is not gzipped. Same (ie no gzip) with wget from Linux